# Best way to programmatically CSS background?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I want to grab an image from my DB, and use that as the background. This is trivial, but is there a better/faster way than my current approach.

Currently, I use Javascript (in the `<head>`) to load my background image, since my CSS is linked and not internal:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').css('background', 'url(/_images/galleries/lg_<?php echo getBackgroundImage(); ?>) no-repeat top center white');
    });
</script>
```

Upon loading the page, it takes about a half second to load the background. I assume the delay can be attributed to loading the external JS, etc. Also, the above code is included as a component, such that I don't have to copy/paste that code in each page of the website. The `<body>` is not encompassed in this included component.

Is there a *FASTER* and preferable approach?

Comment: Since you're adding a script to the document, couldn't you add a `<style>` block with the CSS you need?

Comment: `<body style="background: url(/_images/galleries/lg_<?php echo getBackgroundImage(); ?>) no-repeat top center white">` .. need moar jquery. I still remember the ancient times, when people knew, that CSS was not something provided by jQuery ...

Comment: I could, but didn't know if this was a preferable approach.

Comment: @j08691 add that as an answer. I'll vote for it.

Comment: A "preferable" approach would be to separate HTML from style rules. So to make it proper, I would have included an external stylesheet containing `background-image: url(<?= getBackgroundImage() ?>)`.

Comment: @j08691 , don't add an answer to at topic, which should be closed and wiped from internet

Comment: @Idiqual, best practice is to inline small bits of css. Also, making a dynamic stylesheet that requires another request just for this is not a good idea.

Comment: @user973810: "best practice is to inline small bits of css" <= source ? When I talked about an external CSS, I meant I would've included this rule in my main `style.css`.

Comment: @Idiqual source: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/InlineSmallResources. Also, it can't go in a static stylesheet because it comes from the db.

Comment: @user973810: ok, I guess you're right. Besides, did I mention it was supposed to be a static stylesheet ? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're adding a script to the document you could probably just add a `<style>` block with the CSS you need.

Comment: Thanks, man. Given how popular your comment appears to be, I'll take this as the preferable solution. I was trying to avoid adding a `<style>` block.

Comment: This is a very good answer. It's far better to write code to add a style block than to write code to write code to manipulate a style after the page has already loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance, @ScottSaunders.

Comment: This also re-inforces it, according to the user who provided it in the comments above: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/InlineSmallResources

Answer (score 0):

I see this has been answered already however...

> I assume the delay can be attributed to loading the external JS

Yes. Javascript blocks by default. While there are [ways around this](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/), they depend on defering the loading of the javascript. And you're still having to wait for the javascript to load before it can load the graphic to put in the background. Using j08691's method avoids this issue, but if you want the script to go faster still then [inline the image data](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/) within the CSS file (you could do it in the HTML, but then caching of the image is restricted by caching of the html - usually CSS files will be more cache-able). Of course if you want to support older browsers then you'll need a Varies: User-agent header and different code for non-compliant browsers.

Comment: The delay isn't because of blocking.  This script would hardly block at all, it just wouldn't have any effect until after page load, because of the `.ready()` call.